# Group and subquery issue

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, subquery, greatest-n-per-group

This is my sample data

```
CREATE TABLE customer1
(
  rating int(9),
  genre varchar(100),
  title varchar(100)
  );
    
  INSERT INTO customer1 (rating, genre, title)
  VALUES
(2, 'A', 'abc'),
(4, 'A', 'abc1'),
(2, 'B', 'abc2'),
(3, 'B', 'abc3'),
(2, 'C', 'abc4'),
(5, 'C', 'abc5');
```

I need to find the title with max rating in each genre.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: what if there's a tie?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option uses a subquery for filtering:

```
select c.*
from customer1
where c.rating = (select max(c1.rating) from customer1 c1 where c1.genre = c.genre)
```

This would take advantage of an index on `(genre, rating)`.

In MySQL 8.0, you can also use window functions:

```
select *
from (
    select c.*,
        rank() over(partition by genre order by rating desc) rn
    from customer1 c
) c
where rn = 1
```